# Windows 7 hung during installation -- why and what can I do?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, infinite-loop

I am upgrading from Windows Vista to Windows 7, and the installation process has gone into a loop during the "Expanding Windows Files" step. It is 17% through that step, and just alternates between a message saying "378 of 2224 MB installed" and one saying "please wait."

I would like to save my old files if possible.

Any idea why it may have hung or advice on what to try?

Answer (score 1):

See this for backing up your data, it may be in the original location, but more than likely it is in a folder called windows.old

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/

.

Comment: I would also suggest checking your install media. The disk may be scratched.